# Tap Gesture subview touch detect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitapgesturerecognizer

[image]

i am creating drawer

```
 self.isShowMenuVC = NO;
_menuView = [MenuViewController viewController];
[self.menuView setDelegate:self];
[self addChildViewController:self.menuView];
[self.menuView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(-kMenuTableWidth, 0, kMenuTableWidth, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:self.menuView.view];
[self.menuView didMoveToParentViewController:self];

UITapGestureRecognizer *outsideTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(outsideTapped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:outsideTap];
outsideTap.delegate = self;
```

and when button tap i just set frame of `_menuView.view` to behave like a drawer

what i want is to detect touch outside of drawer but i am not able to do it

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
if (touch.view == self.menuView.view) {
    NSLog(@"Touch Drawer");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Touch Outside");
}

return YES;
}
```

but it is always show **Touch Outside"**

i am missing something but don't know what thanks in advance

Also try with 2 gesture but not working because one gesture in self.view so, when i tap in drawer method call 2 times.

for that i tried to disable one gesture, still calling two times

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

if (gestureRecognizer == self.touchInDrawer) {
    NSLog(@"Touch in drawer");
    [self.touchOutSideDrawer setEnabled:NO];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Outside");
    [self hideMenuView];
}
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this issue with adding two gesture

```
@property (strong,nonatomic)        UITapGestureRecognizer          *touchInDrawer;
@property (strong,nonatomic)        UITapGestureRecognizer          *touchOutSideDrawer;
```

as per  @Eugene Zaychenko's Answer but there is still problem because delegate method calling two times

also i can't  `[self.touchOutSideDrawer setEnabled:NO];` when touch in drawer tapped, because after that it will remove from the view and never executed again if    `[self.touchOutSideDrawer setEnabled:YES];`

but most interesting  thing is

```
_touchInDrawer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(outsideTapped:)];
[self.menuView.view addGestureRecognizer:self.touchInDrawer];
self.touchInDrawer.delegate = self;

_touchOutSideDrawer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(outsideTapped:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.touchOutSideDrawer];
self.touchOutSideDrawer.delegate = self;
```

**outsideTapped** method calling only one time so i shifted my all code there and is working

```
- (void) outsideTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

if (gestureRecognizer == self.touchOutSideDrawer) {
    //  [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.touchOutSideDrawer];
    [self hideMenuView];
    NSLog(@"Outside");

} else {
    NSLog(@"Touch in drawer");

    // [self.touchOutSideDrawer setEnabled:NO];

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The UITapGestureRecognizer cannot detect the touch outside the view which it belongs to.

You need to create another UITapGestureRecognizer and add them to self.menuView.view.

Also you can make two @property for your gesture recognizers and check them inside method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
if (gestureRecognizer == self.firstGesture) {
    NSLog(@"Touch in first gesture");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Touch in another gesture");
}
```

Comment: i tried that not working because i have added gesture in self.view so when i tap on drawer gesture delegate method fire 2 times

Comment: try to implement the method of delegate:

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer

and just return NO;

Comment: Also try to implement the method :

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer

Comment: i did it with          **[self.touchOutSideDrawer setEnabled:NO];**

Comment: but still got issues